# SED command to comment all the lines except the one's that matched the pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, hp-ux

I have the below `cron.txt` file

```
58 18 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP CXC BS TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
00 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh DSC DXC BUS TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP HP SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
03 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh DSC CXC SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
32 10 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh Check CXC OD TODAY MGLA 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
32 12 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh Sca CXC OD TODAY all "01 03 05 07 08 10 12 17 18 19 31 32 33 37 42 50 53 55 57 84 89 93" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP HK SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP RAM SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP SAB SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

And I need to comment (add `#`) at the beginning of all the lines that doesn't have pattern `CXC` or `HP` in it.

I tried

```
grep -iwvE "CXC|HP" cron.txt | sed 's/^/#/g' > cron.txt_bkp
```

It didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your implementation of `grep` supports both the `-w` and the `-E` flag, your `grep` and `sed` pipeline would only extract and comment out the lines that didn't contain `HP` or `CXC`.  The lines that were to be left as-is will not be transferred to the new file.

---

Since [HP-UX `sed`](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/sed.1.html) seems to not support alteration with `|` in regular expressions, which means that `/CXC|HP/!s/^/# /` won't work, you may apply something like this to the file:

```
sed -e '/CXC/b' -e '/HP/b' -e 's/^/# /' crontab.txt >crontab-new.txt
```

The `b` command makes `sed` branch to the end of the editing script if the pattern is found on the current line. It acts as a "print line and continue with next line" command here.

If neither of the first two expressions are acted upon, then the line is commented out by the last expression.

The file `crontab-new.txt`, created above, will hold the following contents given the example in the question:

```
58 18 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP CXC BS TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
# 00 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh DSC DXC BUS TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP HP SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
03 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh DSC CXC SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
32 10 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh Check CXC OD TODAY MGLA 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
32 12 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh Sca CXC OD TODAY all "01 03 05 07 08 10 12 17 18 19 31 32 33 37 42 50 53 55 57 84 89 93" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
# 01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP HK SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
# 01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP RAM SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
# 01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP SAB SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I think you misread the question.  You got it backwards.

Comment: @Wildcard Now properly corrected.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with awk:

```
awk '!/CXC|HP/{$0="#" $0}1' cron.txt > cron.txt_bkp
```

Comment: `gsub()` could be changed to `sub()`.  There is only one single match of `^` in a line... Alternatively, into just `$0 = "#" $0`.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below sed command to achieve the same

cron.txt

```
58 18 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP CXC BS TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
00 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh DSC DXC BUS TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP HP SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
03 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh DSC CXC SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
32 10 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh Check CXC OD TODAY MGLA 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
32 12 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh Sca CXC OD TODAY all "01 03 05 07 08 10 12 17 18 19 31 32 33 37 42 50 53 55 57 84 89 93" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP HK SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP RAM SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP SAB SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

command

```
sed '/HP/!s/^/#/g' cron.txt | sed '/CXC/s/^#//g' >cron.txt_bkp
```

output

```
58 18 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP CXC BS TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
#00 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh DSC DXC BUS TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP HP SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
03 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh DSC CXC SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
32 10 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh Check CXC OD TODAY MGLA 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
32 12 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh Sca CXC OD TODAY all "01 03 05 07 08 10 12 17 18 19 31 32 33 37 42 50 53 55 57 84 89 93" 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
#01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP HK SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
#01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP RAM SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
#01 19 * * 1-5 /usr/home/script.sh REP SAB SNT TODAY all 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: This will definitely work, but it's a tiny bit roundabout way of doing it (adding, then removing comments).

Comment: Kindly vote for my answer